# Как составить запрос в БД mysql

Tags: mysql

Привет всем.
Добавил в БД 94000 записей (долго добавлялось, читая по одной строке из файла)
и получилось что в конце каждой записи стоит \r\n.
Как дать запрос чтобы в каждой записи в конце строки убрать \r\n ?

поля: id, slovo

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: \r\n в полях id и slovo ? или в каком-то одном?

Comment: только в поле slovo

Comment: ответил. тестировал в phpMyAdmin. все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET slovo = REPLACE(slovo, '\\r\\n', '');
```

Comment: UPDATE `slovar` SET `slovo`=REPLACE(`slovo`, '\r\n', '');

вот так прокатило, спасибо. С экранированием \\r\\n не захотело.

Comment: странно, у меня наоборот только с экранированием и сработало

Comment: Чума бэкслеша, все борются как могут =)